# Problem searching sqlite database in kotlin

Tags: database, search, kotlin, android-sqlite, crud

First of all i'm nobbie in Kotlin, trying to learn at home, started making a program for company i work for.
Made SQLite database consists of 4 tables, one of them is "Empeloyees" that have data of employees at the company including departments and professions.
Second table records Holidays taken by those employees.

This is My Main Activity code:

```
class DBHelper(context: Context) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_Name, null, 1) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Empeloyees (EmpID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, EmpName TEXT NOT NULL, EmpProfession TEXT NOT NULL, EmpDepartment TEXT NOT NULL, EmpPhone TEXT NOT NULL, EmpDayofbirth TEXT, EmpMonthofbirth TEXT, EmpYearofbirth TEXT, EmpDayofhire  TEXT, EmpMonthofhire TEXT, EmpYearofhire TEXT)")
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Wardeya (WarID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, WarName TEXT NOT NULL)")
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Permessions (PermID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, EmpName TEXT NOT NULL, Engineer TEXT NOT NULL, Wardeya TEXT NOT NULL, PermDay TEXT NOT NULL, PermMonth TEXT NOT NULL, PermYear TEXT NOT NULL)")
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Holidays (HolidayID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Department TEXT NOT NULL, Profession TEXT NOT NULL, EmpName TEXT NOT NULL, DaysofHoliday TEXT NOT NULL, StartDay TEXT NOT NULL, StartMonth TEXT NOT NULL, StartYear TEXT NOT NULL, EndDay TEXT NOT NULL, EndMonth TEXT NOT NULL, EndYear TEXT NOT NULL, PresentedDay TEXT NOT NULL, PresentedMonth TEXT NOT NULL, PresentedYear TEXT NOT NULL, Engineer TEXT NOT NULL, ApproveDay TEXT NOT NULL, ApproveMonth TEXT NOT NULL, ApproveYear TEXT NOT NULL)")
    }

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Empeloyees")
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Wardeya")
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Permessions")
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Holidays")
    onCreate(db)
}

fun insertDataEmp(id: Int, name: String, prof: String, department: String, phone: String, dayofbirth: String, monthofbirth: String, yearofbirth: String, dayofhire: String, monthofhire: String, yearofhire: String) {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(COL_11, id)
        contentValues.put(COL_12, name)
        contentValues.put(COL_13, prof)
        contentValues.put(COL_14, department)
        contentValues.put(COL_15, phone)
        contentValues.put(COL_16, dayofbirth)
        contentValues.put(COL_17, monthofbirth)
        contentValues.put(COL_18, yearofbirth)
        contentValues.put(COL_19, dayofhire)
        contentValues.put(COL_110, monthofhire)
        contentValues.put(COL_111, yearofhire)
        db.insert(TABLE_EMP, null, contentValues)
    }

    val allDataEmp : Cursor
        get() {
            val db = this.writableDatabase
            val res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMP, null)
            return res
        }
```

Those r for building database and tables.

I've another activity that makes interface to insert Holidays data, like who asked to take a holiday, n which department he works in, n wats his profession. So I started the activity with 2 snippers, one to search for Departments in Empolyees table, n second is to search for professions according to departments:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_holidays_page)
val s1 = spin1

        s1.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent1: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent1: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                DepartmentTextView.text = "${parent1?.selectedItem.toString()}"
            }

        }
val DepartmentList = ArrayList<String>()
        val ProfessionList = ArrayList<String>()
        val db = dbHelper.readableDatabase
        val st1 = "SELECT DISTINCT EmpProfession FROM Empeloyees where EmpDepartment=\'"+DepartmentTextView.text.toString()+"\'"
        val c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT EmpDepartment FROM Empeloyees", null)
        val c2 = db.rawQuery(st1, null)
        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DepartmentList.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("EmpDepartment")))
            }
                while (c1.moveToNext())
                val mySpinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spin1) as Spinner
                var adapter= ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,DepartmentList)
                mySpinner1.adapter = adapter
            }
        if (c2.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ProfessionList.add(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("EmpProfession")))
            }
            while (c2.moveToNext())
            val mySpinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spin2) as Spinner
            var adapter1 = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ProfessionList)
            mySpinner2.adapter = adapter1
        }
    }
```

The first one departments from Employees table and put them in array list n bind it to snipper1 adapter.
My main Problem is the cursor of the second search, I tried all possible solutions ("= Operator", "LIKE Operator", "MATCH Operator"), nothing of them search in the table. But when I change cursor sql string to "SELECT DISTINCT EmpProfession FROM Empeloyees" I get snipper2 adapter.

so any idea where's the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that a selection from spinner1 doesn't drive spinner2 to change. You also have inefficiencies in that if spinner 2 were to be driven by spinner1 then you would build a new adapter each time.

Perhaps consider the following example that incorporates a single function to return the appropriate ArrayList i.e **getArrayList** and functions that manage a single instance of the adapter i.e. **manageSpinner1** and **manageSpinner2** noting that the spinner1's **onItemSelected** invokes **manageSpinner2**.

The example also loads some test data via the **addSomeData** function (this onlt adds data when there is no data).

**Note** for my convenience the layout used is **activity_main.xml** (you would just use your layout).

The activity **MainActivity.kt** is (note that much of your original code has been commented out) :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var selected :String
    var adapter1 :ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
    var adapter2 :ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
    var DepartmentList = ArrayList<String>()
    var ProfessionList = ArrayList<String>()
    var mySpinner1 :Spinner? = null
    var mySpinner2 :Spinner? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val dbHelper = DBHelper(this)
        addSomeData(dbHelper)
        selected = ""
        val s1 = spin1
        mySpinner1 = spin1
        mySpinner2 = spin2
        manageSpinner1(dbHelper)
    }


    private fun addSomeData(dbhlepr :DBHelper) {
        val db = dbhlepr.writableDatabase
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,DBHelper.TABLE_EMP) > 0) return
        dbhlepr.insertDataEmp(1,"Mary","Nurse","Dept1","phone1","14","03","1998","01","01","2005")
        dbhlepr.insertDataEmp(2,"John","Attendant","Dept6","phone1","14","03","1998","01","01","2005")
        dbhlepr.insertDataEmp(3,"Susan","Doctor","Dept15","phone1","14","03","1998","01","01","2005")
        dbhlepr.insertDataEmp(4,"Geoff","Surgeon","Dept25","phone1","14","03","1998","01","01","2005")
    }

    private fun manageSpinner1(dbHelper: DBHelper) {
        DepartmentList.clear()
        DepartmentList.addAll(getArrayList(dbHelper, TYPE_DEPT))
        if (adapter1 == null) {
            adapter1 = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,DepartmentList)
            spin1.adapter = adapter1
            spin1.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent1: AdapterView<*>?) {}

                override fun onItemSelected(parent1: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    selected = "${parent1?.selectedItem.toString()}"
                    manageSpinner2(dbHelper)
                }
            }
        } else {
            adapter1!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun manageSpinner2(dbHelper: DBHelper) {
        Log.d("SPINNER2","Managing Spinner 2 selected department is " + selected)
        ProfessionList.clear()
        ProfessionList.addAll(getArrayList(dbHelper, TYPE_PROF))
        if (adapter2 == null) {
            adapter2 = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ProfessionList)
            spin2.adapter = adapter2
            spin2.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent1: AdapterView<*>?) {}

                override fun onItemSelected(parent1: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                }
            }
        } else {
            adapter2!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun getArrayList(dbHelper: DBHelper, type: Int) :ArrayList<String> {
        var rv = ArrayList<String>()
        var query = ""
        val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
        if (type == TYPE_DEPT) {
            query =" SELECT " + DBHelper.COL_14 + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_EMP + " GROUP BY " + DBHelper.COL_14
        } else {
            query = "SELECT " + DBHelper.COL_13 + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_EMP +
                    " WHERE " + DBHelper.COL_14 + "='" + selected + "'"
                    " GROUP BY " + DBHelper.COL_13
        }
        Log.d("GETARRAYLIST","Query is \n\t" + query)
        val c = db.rawQuery(query,null)
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(c.getString(0))
        }
        c.close()
        return rv
    }

    companion object {
        const val TYPE_DEPT = 1
        const val TYPE_PROF = 2
    }
}
```

## Results

When first run :-

[image]

Spinner1 expanded :-

[image]

**Dept15** selected (profession Doctor):-

[image]

and so on.

Note that Spinner2 could just be a TextView as there will only ever be 1 Profession for a selected department.

Comment: Perfect, Worked very well

Comment: sir I've another problem with my prog, would u help me figure it out?

Comment: @MohammedHelal if you ask a question then there may be a chance that I'll answer.